# Huge SWT/JFace Tables with filtering

Tags: swt, virtual, jface

i want to populate a SWT Virtual Table with a huge amount of rows (up to 3 mio). When i use a lazy content provider i can't use filters and when iI use a normal content provider the performance on changing the filter gets very bad. Is there any way to filter big tables in SWT or JFace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter at the data provider level.

So if your data is coming from a database, use SQL to prefilter your results.

Comment: By setting the viewer input to a prefiltered model?

Comment: My data is not coming from a database and is stored in a big List. I would like to use a HashMap but i'm not sure how to implement a Regex/Substring search with a HashMap (adding entries for each prefix and suffix??)

Comment: Prefiltering is no use... Setting the new input and setting the new item count takes too long! Isn't there a ready to use solution for my problem?